# Javascript in EXT

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

I am using the ext.net framework to develop a project at work. But I have encountered a problem with jQuery's (document).ready function.

Specifically when loading the page the jQuery never seems to be executed.

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var find = $("#NewsPanel");
    var offset = find.offset();
    var top = offset.top - 5;
    var left = offset.left + 70;
    $("#img_NewsnoteOnAll").offset({ top: top, left: left });
    $("#debug").text = top.toString + left.toString();
}
```

If I remove the document ready function it can't fetch the objects.

Comment: You are not closing the `.ready()` (i.e. you are missing a `);` at the end) - is this just an error copy/pasting?

Comment: Always check your developer console for syntax errors and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var find = $("#NewsPanel");
    var offset = find.offset();
    var top = offset.top - 5;
    var left = offset.left + 70;
    $("#img_NewsnoteOnAll").offset({ top: top, left: left });
    $("#debug").text = top.toString + left.toString();
});
```

You forgot `);` at end of line, after last `}`.